# Вычисление выражений с запросом к серверу

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы пользователь вводил текст, т. е. какую-нибудь строку, например, "2+2", программа отправляла этот текст на определенный сайт и присылала ответ?

Comment: Ответ прост - можно.

Comment: а как?что использовать?или есть способ попроще посчитать выражение написанное в строке?

Comment: вводил куда?отсылала куда, в смысле на форму сайта, в строку запроса или куда ещё?ответ в виде чего обычного заголовка?

Comment: Например, на сайте есть калькулятор, считающий выражение. Я хотел бы отправить из формы моей проги строку с выражением, а потом получить ответ с этого сайта в другую строку.

Comment: ещё раз.
Все зависит от того как работает калькулятор, на чем он сделан.
Flash или просто js или же ещё что то?Как передаются параметры?
Телепатичекси догадываюсь что параметры передаются POST/GET запросом. Ну вот и шлете свой POST/GET запрос "сайту". Опять же телепатически догадываюсь что сервер вам даст ответ(врят ли будет по другому), берете и обрабатываете ответ сервера как вашей душе будет угодно

Comment: Калькулятор у меня написан на Xcode для IOS

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите в сторону `NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url usedEncoding:(NSStringEncoding *)enc error:(NSError **)error`. Для синхронного обращения (но так лучше все-таки не делать) или `NSURLConnection` для асинхронного, подробнее это уже будет переписывание справки.

Comment: Можете пример привести как это работает?

Comment: Примеры есть в справке, к тому же я хз какой у Вас протокол обмена с сервером.